# So just rigging a model and after parenting my arms and legs the spine will move the mesh but the limbs wont!

Tags: rigging

So I have made a basic model with more detailed hands for the sake of a game. Now I followed a tutorial and made a basic rig and parented them properly. When i selected the mesh then the skeleton and used automatic weights the spine is able to twist and move the mesh but my arms and legs cannot. The arms were made seperately but the legs were made using symetrize. As the hands were a bit more detailed i made them seperately and parented them to the wrist bone so what have i done wrong here??!?!

Answer (score 0):

Might need to use weight paint mode to put som weight on the mesh from the bones related to arms and legs. If you select the mesh and then go into weight paint mode the parts of the mesh that are affected by your bones will be colored other than blue. You will find each bone that deforms the mesh in vertex groups for the mesh

Comment: so i checked this and im not getting any vertex groups even show up for the arms and legs so i dont get why they arent attached

Comment: Did you parent the armature to the mesh again after you added the arms and legs? Think you need to do that. Could also check in the properties panel for each bone to see if they have the deform box checked

Comment: i basically found out that parenting doesnt work I made one whole skeleton from scratch without parenting (some bones extruding from others instead) and it has worked fine now just need to find out how to export to unity!

Comment: The bones get automatically parented to the bone they are extruded from though. Might be that the parenting of the arms and legs to the rest of the armature went wrong or something